# Email notification when single sign-on certificate has expired

Tags: single-sign-on, certificates

We've implemented single sign-on in our org and. How do we configure email notification when single sign-on certificate expires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific settings need to be enabled to get the email notifications as any users with Modify All Data and View Setup and configuration perms, along with all the system administrators in the org will receive these email notifications on the certificate expiration.